# Editor Integration Image Landscape - Portrait

Tags: shutterstock

Hello I've an image that is portrait, but when i open it the editor shows it in landscape, how to tell the editor to leave portrait or landscape untouched?

My current config:

```
var visualImageEditorConfig = {
  logo: true,
  logoUrl: urlPrefix + '/img/LogoEBSfondoGrigino.png',
  language: 'it’,
  primaryActionText: commonMessages.lblImageVisualEditorSaveButton,
  env: 'prod',
};
```

Comment: Hi @MrCoder, it would be helpful if you could add to the question the relative code to launch the Editor integration, taking care of removing the apikey from the options. Thanks.

Comment: var visualImageEditorConfig = {
       logo: true,
       logoUrl: urlPrefix + '/img/LogoEBSfondoGrigino.png',
       language: 'it’, 
       primaryActionText: commonMessages.lblImageVisualEditorSaveButton,
       env: 'prod',
        };

Comment: From your configuration is unclear what is the method you are using to add an image in the editor. Do you start the editor with an image loaded in the configuration? or do you use addImage later to add it? Do you use URLs or imageData?

Comment: Just to be clear i work at shutterstock, i'm trying to help you.